# Underline + Bold + add link

Tags: links

I'm using a latex template to build my resume and have run into a bit of a debacle. Below is the template I'm using.

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Harshibar
% Based off of: https://github.com/jakeryang/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% only for pdflatex
% \input{glyphtounicode}

% fontawesome
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

% fixed width
\usepackage[scale=0.90,lf]{FiraMono}

% light-grey
\definecolor{light-grey}{gray}{0.83}
\definecolor{dark-grey}{gray}{0.3}
\definecolor{text-grey}{gray}{.08}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ebseries}{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texteb}{\ebseries}

% custom underilne
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}
\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}


% custom font: helvetica-style
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
%% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting - serif
% \titleformat{\section}{
%   \vspace{2pt} \scshape \raggedright\large % header section
% }{}{0em}{}[\color{black} \titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% TODO EBSERIES
% sans serif sections
\titleformat {\section}{
    \bfseries \vspace{2pt} \raggedright \large % header section
}{}{0em}{}[\color{light-grey} {\titlerule[2pt]} \vspace{-4pt}]

% only for pdflatex
% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
% \pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-1pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & {\color{dark-grey}\small #2}\vspace{1pt}\\ % top row of resume entry
      \textit{#3} & {\color{dark-grey} \small #4}\\ % second row of resume entry
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-4pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
            \textbf{#1} & {\color{dark-grey}\small #2}\vspace{1pt}\\ % top row of project entry
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-4pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

% CHANGED default leftmargin  0.15 in
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{0pt}}

\color{text-grey}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge Harshibar} \\ \vspace{5pt}
    \small \faPhone* \texttt{555.555.5555} \hspace{1pt} $|$
    \hspace{1pt} \faEnvelope \hspace{2pt} \texttt{hello@email.com} \hspace{1pt} $|$ 
    \hspace{1pt} \faYoutube \hspace{2pt} \texttt{harshibar} \hspace{1pt} $|$
    \hspace{1pt} \faMapMarker* \hspace{2pt}\texttt{U.S. Citizen}
    \\ \vspace{-3pt}
\end{center}

%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------
\section{EXPERIENCE}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {YouTube}{Aug. 2019 -- Present}
      {Creator (\href{https://www.youtube.com/c/harshibar}{\myuline {@harshibar}})}{San Francisco, CA}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Grew channel to \textbf{60k subscribers in 1.5 years}; created 80+ videos on tech and productivity}
        \resumeItem{Conducted A/B testing on titles and thumbnails; \textbf{increased video impressions by 2.5M} in 3 months}
         \resumeItem{Designed a Notion workflow to streamline video production and roadmapping; boosted productivity by 20\%}
        \resumeItem{\textbf{Partnered with brands like Skillshare and Squarespace} to expand their outreach via sponsorships}
        \resumeItem{\textbf{Highlights}:
            \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhWUjp5pD0g}{\myuline {The Problem with Productivity Apps}}, \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ms4cWMsOITs}{\myuline {Obsidian App Review}},
            \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkDbkyIR44w}{\myuline {Not-So-Minimal Desk Setup}}}
      \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {Google Verily}{Aug. 2018 -- Sept. 2019}
      {Software Engineer}{San Francisco, CA}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{\textbf{Led front-end development} of a dashboard to process 50k blood samples and detect early-stage cancer}
        \resumeItem{Rebuilt a Quality Control product with input from 20 cross-functional stakeholders, \textbf{saving \$1M annually}}
        \resumeItem{Spearheaded product development of a new lab workflow tool, leading to a 40\% increase in efficiency; \\ shadowed 10 core users, iterated on design docs, and implemented the solution with one engineer}

    \resumeItemListEnd


%-----------PROJECTS-----------

\section{PROJECTS}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {Hyku Consulting} {Sept. 2019 -- Mar. 2021}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Mentored 15 students towards acceptance at top US boarding schools; achieved \textbf{100\% success rate}}
            \resumeItem{Designed a \textbf{collaborative learning ecosystem} for students and parents with Trello, Miro, and Google Suite}
          \resumeItemListEnd
          
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd



%-----------EDUCATION-----------
\section {EDUCATION}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Wellesley College}{Aug. 2014 -- May 2018}
      {Bachelor of Arts in Computer Science and Pre-Med}{Wellesley, MA}
        \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem {\textbf{Coursework}: Data Structures, Algorithms, Databases, Computer Systems, Machine Learning}
        \resumeItem 
            {\textbf{Research}: MIT Graybiel Lab (published author), MIT Media Lab (analyzed urban microbe spread)}
        \resumeItemListEnd
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%
%-----------PROGRAMMING SKILLS-----------
\section{SKILLS}
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
     \textbf{Languages} {: Python, JavaScript (React.js), HTML/CSS, SQL (PostgreSQL, MySQL)}\vspace{2pt} \\
     \textbf{Tools}     {: Figma, Notion, Jira, Trello, Miro, Google Analytics, GitHub, DaVinci Resolve, OBS}
    }}
 \end{itemize}


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

I'm looking to add a hyperlink to a website to the Project name, so for example I would like the text 'Hyku Consulting' linked to a website with an underline.

Below is my trial which failed miserably:

1. updated the command to to add link and underline

```
\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
            \textbf{\href{#1}{\myuline {#2}}} & {\color{dark-grey}\small #3}\vspace{1pt}\\ % top row of project entry
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-4pt}
}
```

2. added link address

```
\section{PROJECTS}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {www.google.com}{Hyku Consulting} {Sept. 2019 -- Mar. 2021}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Mentored 15 students towards acceptance at top US boarding schools; achieved \textbf{100\% success rate}}
            \resumeItem{Designed a \textbf{collaborative learning ecosystem} for students and parents with Trello, Miro, and Google Suite}
          \resumeItemListEnd
          
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```

Still, I'm getting a massive error on overleaf. What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: As is is currently defined, `\resumeProjectHeading` accepts 2 arguments but tries to use 3. Hence the error message " Illegal parameter number in definition of \resumeProjectHeading." you get from your example. You may want to use `\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[3]` instead of `\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]` in order to allow for 3 arguments.

Comment: Will all of your project headings contain a hyperlink or just some of them?